# Undefined error when trying to update variables on change

Tags: javascript

I had some code that was working just fine. However, now I am trying to make it so that the pricecalc is recalculated every time the user selects a different option from the select field. Now I get an undefined error in console.

```js
    function pricecalc() {
      var a = document.getElementById("field_0");
      var quantity = a.value.substring(0, 1);
      var b = document.getElementById("field_1");
      var type = b.value;
    
      if (quantity == '2') {
        var rate = '120';
      } else if (quantity == '3') {
        var rate = '110';
      } else {
        var rate = '100';
      }
    
      var price = rate * quantity;
    
      if (type == 'Credit card') {
        var price = price * 1.034;
      }
    
      var price_each = (price / quantity);
      var redirect = 'https://www.paypal.me/' + price;
    
      document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = '£' + price;
      document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = '£' + price_each;
    }
```

```html
This is the HTML

    <select name='field_0' id='field_0' class='text_select' onchange="pricecalc()">
      <option value="2 people">2 people</option>
      <option value="3 people">3 people</option>
      <option value="4 people">4 people</option>
      <option value="5 people">5 people</option>
      <option value="6 people">6 people</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name='field_1' id='field_1' class='text_select' onchange="pricecalc()">
      <option value="Bank transfer">Bank transfer</option>
      <option value="Debit card">Debit card</option>
      <option value="Credit card">Credit card</option>
    </select>
    
    <h4>
    <b>Total Price</b>
    <span id="cost">Hello World!</span>
    <b>Price Each</b>
    <span id="costeach">Hello World!</span>
    </h4>
```

I'm fairly certain this is just an issue with the fact I have put it in a function because outside of a function it works fine. Could anyone please help me understand why my approach to putting it in a function that updates when the select selection is updated is failing?

Here is a link to try it: https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/gwoss8L1/2/

Comment: The code seems to be functioning properly. Your error must be related to some other code on the page. Voting to close.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't work properly. That's why you see "hello world" instead of price values

Comment: The error you're getting in the Fiddle demo is due to the inline "onclick" in your HTML.  JS Fiddle doesn't like that.  You could achieve the same result using JS addEventListener.  Updated Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/gwoss8L1/5/

Comment: @Jimmy When you run the code right here in the Code Snippet I created for you, it works without error. You don't get "Hello World".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a jsfiddle config thing.

In the js menu change "Load Type" to:
`No wrap - in <body>`"

It was set to `onLoad` so i guess the function wasn't created yet.

[image]

Comment: @Vasan Yeah, but i dislike `js` code in the head of the document :)

Comment: Thank you for this. This does work. However, the issue is, on my website it still doesn't work. However when I copy the exact code into jsfiddle and run it with no wrap in body then it does work - what would this mean?

Comment: where and when are you loading your code in your website?

Comment: The javascript after the form. I can link you, one moment

Comment: Sorry about all the extra JS code but if you search for pricecalc it will show up

Comment: seems like `function pricecalc` is nested under `function PHPFMG(formID) {`. it is not globally accessible